# Are Youtube style loaders the next big UI trend?

Tags: gui-design, ajax, jquery

Given that we are in an age where there are a lot of single page applications and AJAX calls are abound, are youtube style AJAX loaders a good replacement to the loading gifs? Its such a simple addition that makes a lot of sense. Is this usable enough to let people understand that we are loading some content and that loading bar is showing the progress?

http://nanobar.micronube.com/

http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/

Comment: Although simple, attractive and usually useful, I don't think we can say if it's going to be massively adopted or not. Some sites will use it, some won't.

Comment: I voted to close this question, as it is primarily opinion based. Predicting trends is a guessing game.

Comment: I agree, and I also voted to close.  However, you could get the question on topic for this site if you frame it around the usability of the technique rather than its (potential) popularity.

Comment: Progress bars aren't exactly a new concept.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesWesley I have edited my question now to be less opinion based and more UX related. Hope this works!

Comment: @DA01 This isn't exactly a progress bar. Its more of a loading bar. Same concept different application

Comment: I guess I don't understand the difference. Isn't a progress part showing you the state of what is loading and how much is left?

Comment: But, I suppose what is new is that it's a bit easier to make these accurate. In the past, the reason they weren't used all that much was that it was a chore to show 'true' progress. Flash could do it fairly easily, hence seeing a ton of them in Flash files. These days, the technology and bandwidth is there to make these more accurate--which is good, as they do provide more feedback than a spinner.